# How to check if at least one key in dictionary exists as a value in another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I am creating a function that accepts a dictionary1 and checks if any of the keys exists as a value dictionary2.

I have tried using the `dictionary2.isdisjoint(dictionary1)` but this is effective for only checking keys-keys.

How can I check key to value in Python?

Comment: They tried "dictionary2.isdisjoint(dictionary1)". Perhaps they could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @caricature please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the below statement returns `True` (it will return common values) then:

```
set(dictionary1.keys()) & set(dictionary2.values())
```

**Explanation:**

- `dictionary1.keys()` will give the list of keys in dictionary1
- `dictionary2.values()` will give the list of values in dictionary2
- Convert these two to `set` and if they have common values, you will end
  up with the common values between the two.

> ```
> dictionary1 = {1:2, 2:3, 3:4}
> dictionary2 = {2:1, 2:3, 3:4}
> print set(dictionary1.keys()) & set(dictionary2.values())
> ```

**Output:**

```
set([3])
```

Comment: `set(dictionary1) & set(dictionary2.values())` is even better

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is really a big enough task to put into a separate function, but anyway, here's an example using the [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) keyword:

```
if any(k in d2.values() for k in d1.keys()):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Elegant and pythonic way.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an operation that is built-in.  You would need to write logic to do it yourself.  You seem to be using python 3, so something like the below might work

```py
>>> x = dict.fromkeys([0, 5, 10])
>>> y = {x: x for x in range(5)}
>>> print(x.keys().isdisjoint(y.values()))
False
>>> x.pop(0)
>>> print(x.keys().isdisjoint(y.values()))
True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four'}
d2 =  {'5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'eight', 'three': '3', '9': 'nine'}

for key in d:
    if key in d2.itervalues():
        print "found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost right. You have to add `not` to proof the opposite (not disjoint == have common elements) and use the method `values()` to get values from the dictionary. In your case you check only keys of two dictionaries.

```
d1 = {i: i for i in range(5)}
d2 = {i: j for i, j in zip(range(5), range(5,10))}
d3 = {i: j for i, j in zip(range(5,10), range(5))}

print('d1: ', d1)
print('d2: ', d2)

print('Keys of d1 in values of d2: ', not set(d1).isdisjoint(d2.values()))
print('Keys of d1 in keys of d2: ', not set(d1).isdisjoint(d2))
print()

print('d2: ', d2)
print('d3: ', d3)

print('Keys of d2 in values of d3: ', not set(d2).isdisjoint(d3.values()))
print('Keys of d2 in keys of d3: ', not set(d2).isdisjoint(d3))
```

#### Output:

```
# d1:  {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
# d2:  {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9}
# Keys of d1 in values of d2:  False
# Keys of d1 in keys of d2:  True
# 
# d2:  {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9}
# d3:  {5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 4}
# Keys of d2 in values of d3:  True
# Keys of d2 in keys of d3:  False
```